# Encoding H264 videos for Android, advice needed

Tags: android, video, air, h.264

After porting my iOS app to a new tablet I bought a couple of days ago, I've noticed that my videos weren't playing when using StageVideo.

I was using a high quality video (the tablet has a 2560x1600 resolution and the video occupies 2/3 of the screen) and what happened was that I got a black screen (with sound) after I click "play" in the stream.

After lots of tests and googling, I've found out that the issue was the video I was using, or at least it was part of the problem.

When I switched the high quality video for another one of a lower quality and suspect specs too, the video started just fine.

So a new world opens before me, the encoding universe, which I know nothing about.

Any experience about this is very welcomed, since start to investigate about encoding to gain non-trivial knowledge would be very time consuming for what I've read.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit general so I think the best starting point will be to go over this: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html